# Opening a Debian package file without `dpkg`

Tags: debian, osx, deb

I need to open a Debian `deb` package file in MacOS High Sierra to compare a binary with one that I have installed in Linux.

Actually the package is `mssql-server_14.0.3008.27-1_amd64.deb`

The `file` command says `Debian binary package (format 2.0)`.

`tar x` and `unzip` do not work.

What to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The outer layer of the actual `.deb` file is actually an `ar` archive.

As unpacking/opening it will be generating some files, we would better move it to a directory:

```
$ mkdir debtmp
$ mv mssql-server_14.0.3008.27-1_amd64.deb 
$ cd debtmp
```

So as a first step, to unpack it, we do:

```
$ ar xv mssql-server_14.0.3008.27-1_amd64.deb 
x - debian-binary
x - control.tar.gz
x - data.tar.xz
```

As for the resulting files, `debian-binary` just contains the .deb format version:

```
$ cat debian-binary 
2.0
```

`control.tar.gz` contains the apt/dpkg info including post/pre/install scripts, dependencies and a checksum file. So we are not actually much interested on it for now.

```
$ tar -tvf control.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   root        0 18 Nov 04:55 ./
-rw-r--r--  0 root   root      546 18 Nov 04:55 ./control
-rw-r--r--  0 root   root       25 18 Nov 04:55 ./shlibs
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root      383 18 Nov 04:55 ./preinst
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root      107 18 Nov 04:55 ./config
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root      289 18 Nov 04:55 ./postrm
-rw-r--r--  0 root   root        0 18 Nov 04:54 ./templates
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root      251 18 Nov 04:55 ./prerm
-rw-r--r--  0 root   root       60 18 Nov 04:55 ./triggers
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root      771 18 Nov 04:55 ./postinst
-rw-r--r--  0 root   root     6155 18 Nov 04:55 ./md5sums
```

We are then much more interested in the `data.tar.zx` file, as it contains the configuration files and executable files.

First, we need to install `xz`, using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org),  as `tar` will need to invoke it, as we are dealing in this `.deb` file with a `.tar.xz`.

```
sudo port install xz
```

Note: It has been called to my attention in the comments you might also deal with `.tar.gz` and `.tar.gz` in other .debs -- however macOS comes with `gunzip` and `bzip2` installed by default.

So, to unpack it:

```
$ tar xvf data.tar.xz 
x ./
x ./opt/
x ./opt/mssql/
x ./opt/mssql/bin/
x ./opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
x ./opt/mssql/bin/crash-support-functions.sh
[snip]
x ./usr/share/doc/mssql-server/license_Std_Linux.txt.gz
x ./usr/share/doc/mssql-server/license_Eval_Linux_Chinese (Simplified).txt.gz
x ./usr/share/doc/mssql-server/license_Std_Linux_French.txt.gz
x ./lib/
x ./lib/systemd/
x ./lib/systemd/system/
x ./lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service
```

Finally, having all the files on the local disk, the binary can be fetched from the directory `opt/mssql/bin/`

Additional notes: As per @AustinHemmelgarn excellent remarks, the last step could also encounter a `gzip` or `bzip2` instead of a `xz` compression in other `.deb` files.

Comment: It is worth nothing that depending on the vintage of the package, the actual data archive may not be xz compressed (it as originally gzip compressed, and then bzip2, both of which are still supported, and I've heard rumors that  the dpkg team may be looking at zstandard support in the near future).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I am focusing on actual packages. Good point, thanks.

Comment: The compression in use doesn’t depend on the `.deb` version, version 2.0 packages can use `gzip` etc. too.